# 1999 Camaro engine noise

Tags: engine, noise, camaro

So I was driving the other day, right before my engine over heated (I don't think its relevant to the noise or it might be) and my engine started kinda knocking sounds kinda like a clacking noise. When I turn the wheel it sorta screeches and then stops. When you rev it or take off the noise speeds up. It usually doesn't do it at speed. Also when you let off the accelerator it gets louder and faster. My ex had this same issue with her civic. I'm at a loss because I didn't know what was wrong with her car much less my Camaro. V6 automatic 3800 series

Comment: So the clacking sound speeds up or the screeching does? How is the belt? Pulleys? Engine oil? Can you record it?

Answer (score 1):

Might be rod knock or the pump going bad since I’m increases with rpm and at crushing rpm is low so the issues like these are masked. Something rubbing on the belt causing squealing?